# vba - saving file to my personal desktop code

Tags: vba, substitution, save-as

I have the following code which is designed so I can quick save to my desktop and then put the file into a folder. This code works fine if the file is already saved in an .xls, .csv, .xlsx or .xlsm file extension, however, when the file IS NOT saved, I only get the pop-up message boxes, and nothing happens. I was thinking about re-structuring using a CASE STATEMENT with right(activeworkbook.name, 4), but didn't know how to structure as I am not familiar with these statements.  Thank you.

```
Sub SavetoDesktop()

'this macro will save the activesheet into the default path giving it the current name and xlsx extension

    Dim fname As String

'    If Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 5) <> ".xlsx" And Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 5) <> ".xls" And _
'    Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 5) <> ".xlsm" And Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 5) <> ".csv" Then

                 If Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
                         fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsx", "") & ".xlsx"
                         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
                 Else
                     MsgBox "Not an .xlsx file!"
                     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\mmirabelli\Desktop\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".xlsx"
                 End If

                 If Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 4) = ".csv" Then
                         fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".csv", "") & ".csv"
                         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
                 Else
                     MsgBox "Not an .csv file!"
                     MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name

                 End If

                 If Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 4) = ".xls" Then
                         fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "") & ".xls"
                         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
                  Else
                     MsgBox "Not an .xls file!"
                  End If

                 If Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 5) = ".xlsm" Then
                         fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", "") & ".xlsm"
                         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
                 Else
                    MsgBox "Not an .xlsm file!"
                 End If

'     Else
'
'     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\mmirabelli\Desktop\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".xlsx"

'     End If


'MsgBox Application.DefaultFilePath
'MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
'
'    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
'
End Sub
```

Comment: If the `ActiveWorkbook` is a fresh new workbook that is not saved yet, its name will be something like `Book1` so it wont match any of those extensions. What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: In the case where the excel file is extracted from a separate application (and has a pre-determined file name) or in the case where a new book (Book1) is created, I would like it save as the current name (whichever of the 2 it is) - so Book1.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
Sub SavetoDesktop()
    'this macro will save the activesheet into the default path giving it the current name and xlsx extension
    Dim fname As String
    Select Case True
        Case ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*.xlsx", _
             ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*.xlsm", _
             ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*.xls", _
             ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*.csv"
             fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
        Case Else
            msgBox "No file extension. Will be saved as .xlsx in the Desktop folder"
            fname = Environ$("HOMEDRIVE") & Environ$("HOMEPATH") & "\Desktop\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".xlsx"
    End Select

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
    msgBox IIf(Err.Number, "Could not Save", "Saved")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this out and found the following:

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response. I tried this out and found the following: 1) The msgbox popped up when I tried saving Book1, and then it said "could not save" , and it did not save to desktop. For already saved files, I just got the "could not save" msgbox. I've never seen the "LIKE" and the "*" syntax (at least in VBA, have seen in SQL). Is the like used for patterns in strings? and does the "*" function as a wildcard for anything before or after? I also used a select case statement and found it was successful. I'll post below. Thanks again for the reply.

```
Sub SavetoDesktop()

'this macro will save the activesheet into the default path giving it the current name and xlsx extension,
' unless it already has an extension of the 4 most common formats, then it will simply save over 
'(replace) the current file w a prompt


Dim fname As String

On Error GoTo errormessage

Select Case Right(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 4)
Case "xlsx"
fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsx", "") & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
Case ".xls"
fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "") & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
Case "xlsm"
fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", "") & ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
Case ".csv"
fname = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".csv", "") & ".csv"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
Case Else
MsgBox "Saved to desktop as .xlsx file!"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\mmirabelli\Desktop\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".xlsx"
End Select

Exit Sub

errormessage:
MsgBox "No action", vbInformation + vbOKCancel, Time()

End Sub
```